# Pnotify Implementation Server side

Tags: c#, alert, pnotify

I want to implement a server side Pnotify function in ASP.NET/C#. Please help I have tried, but nothing is happening. I am also using a master page.

```
$(function () {
    new PNotify({
        title: 'Regular Notice',
        text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.',
        type: 'success',
        cornerclass: 'ui-pnotify-sharp',
        styling: 'bootstrap3'
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to implement server side? Do you want to get notifications from the server?

Comment: yes, i have all value like title, text etc but i m not able to call this function (Pnotify) server side when i get any error or exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in head section of page. this worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function () {
    new PNotify({
        title: 'Regular Notice',
        text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.',
        type: 'success',
        cornerclass: 'ui-pnotify-sharp',
        styling: 'bootstrap3'
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: Does this allow a notification from the server like the OP was looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Theme JS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/notifications/pnotify.min.js"></script>
```

You need to upload the pnotify Javascript files at the top of the page.